# sql beginner is there a command so i cannot pass an empty value into a table?

Tags: sql

I'm a SQL beginner. Is there a command so I cannot pass an empty value into a table?

The `NOT NULL` statement hinders from explicitly entering a `NULL` value and `DEFAULT` statement will automatically enter a default value, if empty value is entered.

But is there a way to stop entering empty values all together?

By "empty values" I mean ->

```
insert into tableCats ( ) values ();
```

if `tableCats` had two columns `Name` and `Age` with default values then I just created a row with default values. But is there a way to stop -> values () so it cant happen accidentally?

Comment: What do you mean with _empty values_?

Comment: Are you looking for a check constraint that prevents `''`?

Comment: with empty values i mean ->  insert into tableCats ( ) values ();   if tableCats had to colums Name and Age with default values then i just created a row with default values. But is there a way to stop -> values ()  so it cant happen accidentially ?

Comment: `NOT NULL` without a `DEFAULT` prevents all updates and inserts from writing `NULL`, including implicit writes such as `insert into mytable (col_a) values (123)` when col_b is a not null column.

Answer (score 0):

> if tableCats had two colums Name and Age with default values then i
>   just created a row with default values

...if you don't want to allow that, then make the columns `NOT NULL`, and don't set any default values for them. That way, if someone tries to insert a row without specifying a value for those columns, the database engine will return an error.